# filter json file with python

Tags: python, json

How to filter a json file to show only the information I need?

To start off I want to say I'm fairly new to python and working with JSON so sorry if this question was asked before and I overlooked it.

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Store": 417,
        "Item": 10,
        "Name": "Burger",
        "Modifiable": true,
        "Price": 8.90,
        "LastModified": "09/02/2019 21:30:00"
    },
    {
        "Store": 417,
        "Item": 15,
        "Name": "Fries",
        "Modifiable": false,
        "Price": 2.60,
        "LastModified": "10/02/2019 23:00:00"
    }
]
```

I need to filter this file to only show `Item` and `Price`, like

```
[
    {
        "Item": 10,
        "Price": 8.90
    },
    {
        "Item": 15,
        "Price": 2.60
    }
]
```

I have a code that looks like this:

```
# Transform json input to python objects
with open("StorePriceList.json") as input_file:
    input_dict = json.load(input_file)

# Filter python objects with list comprehensions
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if ] #missing logical test here.

# Transform python object back into json
output_json = json.dumps(output_dict)

# Show json
print(output_json)
```

What logical test I should be doing here to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say we can use dict comprehension, then it will be

```
output_dict = [{k:v for k,v in x.items() if k in ["Item", "Price"]} for x in input_dict]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this :)

```
>>> [{key: d[key] for key in ['Item', 'Price']} for d in input_dict] # you should rename it to `input_list` rather than `input_dict` :)
[{'Item': 10, 'Price': 8.9}, {'Item': 15, 'Price': 2.6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
        qe = json.load(f)
        list = []
        for item in qe['<your data>']: 
            query = (f'{item["Item"]} {item["Price"]}')

        print("query")
```