# Filter in json file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "teste",
        "name_test": 3,
        "external_id": "12345",
        "id_job": 14,
        "active": true,
        "email": "teste@teste.com",
        "phone_country": "55",
        "start_date": "1970-01-01",
        "created_at": "2019-07-15 20:22:44",
        "created_by": 122,
        "created_by_name": "teste"
    },
    {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "teste",
        "name_test": 3,
        "external_id": "12345",
        "id_job": 67,
        "active": true,
        "email": "teste@teste.com",
        "phone_country": "55",
        "start_date": "1970-01-01",
        "created_at": "2019-07-15 20:22:44",
        "created_by": 122,
        "created_by_name": "teste"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "teste",
        "name_test": 3,
        "external_id": "12345",
        "id_job": 21,
        "active": false,
        "email": "teste@teste.com",
        "phone_country": "55",
        "start_date": "1970-01-01",
        "created_at": "2019-07-15 20:22:44",
        "created_by": 122,
        "created_by_name": "teste"
    }
]
```

I need to filter only "active": true  AND "id_job": 14,67

Here is my code I've trying,

```
result['data'] = [x for x in result['data'] if x['id_job'] in [14,67] and x['active'] == 'true']
```

The result should be like this

```
    [
    {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "teste",
        "name_test": 3,
        "external_id": "12345",
        "id_job": 14,
        "active": true,
        "email": "teste@teste.com",
        "phone_country": "55",
        "start_date": "1970-01-01",
        "created_at": "2019-07-15 20:22:44",
        "created_by": 122,
        "created_by_name": "teste"
    },
    {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "teste",
        "name_test": 3,
        "external_id": "12345",
        "id_job": 67,
        "active": true,
        "email": "teste@teste.com",
        "phone_country": "55",
        "start_date": "1970-01-01",
        "created_at": "2019-07-15 20:22:44",
        "created_by": 122,
        "created_by_name": "teste"
    }
]
```

but as result I receive this

```
[
    [],
    []
]
```

My question is similar this one [filter json file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672856/filter-json-file-with-python), but I need to put value in the filter

Comment: `true != 'true'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you're getting data out of your json file and into python so I'm going to make some quick code to do that first, assuming your file is called `data.json`

```
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

`data` will now be an array that holds dictionary entries.

In your code above you are using the outer most object like a dictionary which is not what the object you gave shows.

Also you're checking for `"true"` which is a `str`.  When you load this data using the json library it will be the python value of `True`

So then your filtered data can be created using the following

```
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] in [14,67] and x['active'] == True]
```

If you know your json will always have the boolean values of `true` and `false` for the `active` field you can actually simplify the above down to

```
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['id_job'] in [14,67] and x['active']]
```

Comment: oh gosh, it was too close cause I had already tried but as 'true' not True. Its work fine right now. Thank you so much sedavidw

Answer (score 0):

```
result['data'] = [x for x in result['data'] if x['id_job'] in [14,67] and x['active'] == True]
```

x['active'] is decoded by the json.loads package.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table

[image]